# how to fix wine error: `RtlpWaitForCriticalSection` timeout error

Tags: kali-linux, wine

Hello i am a new user to wine. i am currently using the stable version of winehq **(wine-7.0.1)**
. initially i could run games using the wine command but after i tried to install vitual dj player the program launched but i could not do anything with it. the screen displayed the program interface but it was not interactive . trying to run the games that were initially  working with wine i experience the following scenarios.
NBA 2K20 does not run completely and i get an error continuously **fixme** followed by **RtlpWaitForCriticalSection**  which is made up of four threads trapped in a continuous loop.the terminal output is as shown below

**fixme error**

```
0104:fixme:nstc:NSTC2_fnSetControlStyle2 mask & style (0x00000004) contains unsupported style(s): 0x00000004
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1026, a003, 0, 0068F56C)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1026, a004, 1, 0068F56C)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1025, a003, 1, 0068F56C)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1025, a004, 1, 0068F56C)
0080:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x41130, 0): stub
0080:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010020, 0000000000041130): stub
0104:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x259118, 1): stub
0104:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0001004C, 00259118): stub
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnOnViewWindowActive stub, 00247B78 (00258FB8)
0104:err:shell:HCR_GetFolderAttributes should be called for simple PIDL's only!
0104:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x0000000c
012c:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000021D270 0000000000000000): stub
0140:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0140, blocked by 012c, retrying (60 sec)
0104:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x0000000c
0148:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000021D270 0000000000000000): stub
015c:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 015c, blocked by 0148, retrying (60 sec)
0140:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0140, blocked by 012c, retrying (60 sec)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1026, a003, 0, 0068E6DC)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1026, a004, 1, 0068E6DC)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1025, a003, 1, 0068E6DC)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1025, a004, 1, 0068E6DC)
015c:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 015c, blocked by 0148, retrying (60 sec)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1026, a003, 0, 0068EC7C)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1026, a004, 1, 0068EC7C)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1025, a003, 1, 0068EC7C)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1025, a004, 1, 0068EC7C)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnOnViewWindowActive stub, 00247B78 (00262150)
0104:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x0000000c
0174:err:winediag:ntlm_check_version ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0174:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
0174:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 00000000 1 00000000 0 stub
0174:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0174:fixme:wbemprox:wbem_services_CreateInstanceEnum unsupported flags 0x00000030
0174:fixme:wbemprox:enum_class_object_Next timeout not supported
0174:fixme:ddraw:ddraw7_Initialize Ignoring guid {aeb2cdd4-6e41-43ea-941c-8361cc760781}.
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:alsa:get_alsa_name_by_guid No devices found in registry?
0174:err:winediag:MIDIMAP_drvOpen No software synthesizer midi port found, Midi sound output probably won't work.
0174:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (000900B6, 00000000): stub
0174:fixme:d3d9:D3DPERF_SetOptions (0x1) : stub
0174:fixme:service:I_ScRegisterDeviceNotification Notification filters are not yet implemented.
0224:fixme:service:I_ScRegisterDeviceNotification Notification filters are not yet implemented.
0174:fixme:process:SetProcessPriorityBoost (FFFFFFFF,1): stub
0174:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (000004F0 0): stub
0174:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (000004F4 1): stub
0174:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (000004F8 2): stub
0174:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (000004FC 3): stub
0174:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (00000500 4): stub
0174:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (00000504 5): stub
01ec:fixme:d3d:state_linepattern_w Setting line patterns is not supported in OpenGL core contexts.
0140:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0140, blocked by 012c, retrying (60 sec)
01ec:fixme:d3d:swapchain_blit_gdi Using GDI present.
01ec:err:d3d:swapchain_blit_gdi Failed to get destination DC.
01ec:err:d3d:swapchain_blit_gdi Failed to blit.
015c:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 015c, blocked by 0148, retrying (60 sec)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1026, a003, 0, 0068EC7C)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1026, a004, 1, 0068EC7C)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1025, a003, 1, 0068EC7C)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 00247B78 (2, 1025, a004, 1, 0068EC7C)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnOnViewWindowActive stub, 00247B78 (0025C8B0)
0104:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x0000000c
0290:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000021D270 0000000000000000): stub
02a4:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 02a4, blocked by 0290, retrying (60 sec)
0140:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0140, blocked by 012c, retrying (60 sec)
015c:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 015c, blocked by 0148, retrying (60 sec)
02a4:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 02a4, blocked by 0290, retrying (60 sec)
0140:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0140, blocked by 012c, retrying (60 sec)
015c:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 015c, blocked by 0148, retrying (60 sec)
02a4:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 02a4, blocked by 0290, retrying (60 sec)
0140:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0140, blocked by 012c, retrying (60 sec)
015c:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 015c, blocked by 0148, retrying (60 sec)
02a4:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 02a4, blocked by 0290, retrying (60 sec)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnOnViewWindowActive stub, 00247B78 (0025C8B0)
0140:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0140, blocked by 012c, retrying (60 sec)
0104:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnOnViewWindowActive stub, 00247B78 (0025C8B0)
0104:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x0000000c
02ac:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000021D270 0000000000000000): stub
```

**RtlpWaitForCriticalSection ** trapped in a looping cycle of four threads

```
02c0:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 02c0, blocked by 02ac, retrying (60 sec)
015c:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 015c, blocked by 0148, retrying (60 sec)
02a4:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 02a4, blocked by 0290, retrying (60 sec)
0140:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0140, blocked by 012c, retrying (60 sec)

02c0:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 02c0, blocked by 02ac, retrying (60 sec)
015c:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 015c, blocked by 0148, retrying (60 sec)
02a4:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 02a4, blocked by 0290, retrying (60 sec)
0140:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0000000170065600 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0140, blocked by 012c, retrying (60 sec)
```

fortunately i can still run pes2017 still launches and runs. i have no clue as to what causes the problem but from the research i have carried out it seem to be a bug . the unfortunate thing is that from all forums i have visited such as winehq forums no one seem to have a solution... anyone with a guided solution and explanation to what the problem will be of great help

Comment: Try the latest development version of wine as well. If that doesn't help, and it works on Windows but not under Wine, then it is a bug that needs to be reported. There's not much to add. You can try to fix it as well if you're brave enough.